# Alpha Composite in Android SDK

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am a little new to Mobile Development with Android SDK and alphacomposite does not exist as a class within the SDK is there an equivalent for android SDK?

I've tried downloading the original version of the class alphacomposite from Javas official libraries and copying it over but it was to heavily dependent